# explode function spark python

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, flatten

I have the following data structure in JSON file and would like to flatten the data.

```
    root
 |-- _embedded: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _links: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- self: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- associations: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ERP_PIM: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- product_models: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- PACK: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- product_models: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- SUBSTITUTION: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- product_models: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- UPSELL: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- product_models: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- X_SELL: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- product_models: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- products: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- categories: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- created: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- family: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- identifier: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- workflow_status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- parent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- updated: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Contrex_table: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- data: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- locale: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- scope: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- UFI_Table: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- UFI: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- company: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- locale: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- scope: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- add_reg_info: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- data: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- locale: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- scope: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- adr_transport_class: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- data: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- locale: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- scope: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- adr_transport_label: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- locale: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- scope: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- adr_tunnel_restriction_code: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- data: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- locale: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- scope: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- allergen: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- locale: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- scope: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- api: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- data: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- locale: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- scope: string (nullable = true)

 |-- _links: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- first: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- next: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- self: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
```

short version of data.

```
 {"items": [
        {
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "products\/PCR-0006894-SAMKG0-PC"
                }
            },
            "identifier": "pcr-1",
            "enabled": true,
            "family": "products",
            "categories": [
                "239",
                "CL1_MEA",
                "D00",
                "D001",
                "EMEA",
                "MAR",
                "MARKET_SEGMENT_VIEW",
                "PC",
                "Validated_SHEQ"
            ],
            "groups": [],
            "parent": "PCR-0006894-SAMKG0"

        }]}
```

[image]

Goal is to not mentione `keys` manually but explode only the one which `values` are `str` type.

I have this code where I im trying to flatten the entire json file:

```
def flatten_df(nested_df):
    flat_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] != 'struct']
    nested_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] == 'struct']

    flat_df = nested_df.select(flat_cols +
                               [F.col(nc+'.'+c).alias(nc+'_'+c)
                                for nc in nested_cols
                                for c in nested_df.select(nc+'.*').columns])
    return flat_df
```

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: can you add a sample of your data, not as an image ?

Comment: unfortunelty, I cant

Comment: only 2 or 3 rows, you can obfuscate the data if it's sensitive data

Comment: I modified with sample data

Comment: What do you mean by explode string values? Can you provide the expected output for the above example?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham I have updated the post with desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the sample data that you have given (added another element to items array). Then, I have created a dataframe from this data.

```
data = '''{
   "items":[
      {
         "_links":{
            "self":{
               "href":"products\/PCR-0006894-SAMKG0-PC"
            }
         },
         "identifier":"pcr-1",
         "enabled":"true",
         "family":"products",
         "categories":[
            "239",
            "CL1_MEA",
            "D00",
            "D001",
            "EMEA",
            "MAR",
            "MARKET_SEGMENT_VIEW",
            "PC",
            "Validated_SHEQ"
         ],
         "groups":[
            
         ],
         "parent":"PCR-0006894-SAMKG0",
         "created":"2021-01-01T12:00:00+00:00",
         "updated":"2021-01-01T12:00:00+00:00"
      },
      {
         "_links":{
            "self":{
               "href":"products\/PCR-0006894-SAMKG0-PC"
            }
         },
         "identifier":"pcr-2",
         "enabled":"true",
         "family":"products",
         "categories":[
            "239",
            "CL1_MEA",
            "D00",
            "D001",
            "EMEA",
            "MAR",
            "MARKET_SEGMENT_VIEW",
            "PC",
            "Validated_SHEQ"
         ],
         "groups":[
            
         ],
         "parent":"PCR-0006783-SAMKG0",
         "created":"2022-04-01T12:00:00+00:00",
         "updated":"2022-04-01T12:00:00+00:00"
      }
   ]
}'''

x = []
x.append(data)
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(x))
#df.printSchema()
```

[image]

- Now, I have used `explode` function on the `items` column to create a new dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

df1 = df.select(explode(df.items).alias('required'))
df1.printSchema()
```

[image]

- Now, I have created another dataframe selecting all the columns from `required` struct column using the following code:

```
df2 = df1.select('required.*')
display(df2)
```

[image]

- Now, using the following code, I have created an array containing column names whose type is `string`.

```
req_cols = []
for col_name,col_type in df2.dtypes:
    #print(col_name,col_type)
    if(col_type == 'string'):
        req_cols.append(col_name)
print(req_cols)
```

[image]

- Now you can use the above array to select the required columns from the `df2` dataframe.

```
display(df2.select(*req_cols))
```

[image]

Comment: will this work on multiple nested json too?

Comment: This code would work only if the JSON is present as given in your example (or data that I have taken). But the idea would be similar to the above code.

Comment: If the schema (given in your image) is how the actual data is present, the first apply `df = start_df.select('embeded.*')` (start_df is the initial dataframe after reading your json). Now `df` would have schema same as in my answer (1st image) and you can continue from there to get data as desired.

Comment: I have modifed the post, with the `printSchema` and my code, I will take alook at your and try to modify but could please see what Im doing wrong with my code. Basically Im trying the same thing you did, to flatten whole JSON file. I think I need to go into more hierarchy with more for loops. But no clue how

Comment: change your condition for flat_cols list comprehension to `flat_cols = [c[0] for c in nested_df.dtypes if c[1][:6] == 'string']` and try.

Comment: it does not make sense it returns empty list in both ways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251206/discussion-between-saideep-arikontham-and-greencolor).